# MS Access/SQL Question: How to split strings?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've a table which looks like this

```
[name_attr][visted_places_attr]
 peter      zurich paris tokyo
 max        nyc london prague
 max        stockholm
```

The cities are delimited by a white space. If there are more than three cities, they're listed in a new row. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the cities separately (and delimited) in a new table of this form:

```
[name_attr][visited_place_attr] 
 peter      zurich
 peter      paris
 peter      tokyo
 max        nyc
 max        london
 <...>
```

I Appreciate any input.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that cities are separated by one, and only one, space, you can use the split function, that returns an array of items (Each item a city). I don't know the source of the data, but there are cities with spaces inside the name, p. e. "San Paoulo". The aproximation of split by space is not alwais valid.

For generate the output table you can use the following algoritm (not probed):

```
nameAttr = rs!name_attr
do while nameAttr = rs!name_attr
    cities = split(rs!visted_places_attr, " ")
    for each city in cities
        rsTarget.AddNew
        rsTarget!name_attr = nameAttr
        rsTarget!visited_place_attr = city
        rsTarget.Update
    next
    rs.MoveNext
    if rs.eof then exit do
loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I'm looking for a way to do this via SQL (right now I'm trying to apply http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/fyi-sql-splitting-delimited-concatenated-string-into-separate-strings-rows-t1171660.html but I can't figure it out..)

Comment: Doing it in SQL would likely involve some ugly UNION queries that parse the city field based on the number of spaces in them. This is a one-time operation, right? So why not just use the code above, which is much simpler than anything you'll end up with in SQL.